# Verify a field is not empty

Tags: theming, 8

What is the best method to check if a field is empty in a node template.

In node--example.html.twig we can use "content" variable.

I can't use check like checking a block

```
{% if content.field_example  %}
```

I can use something like this:

```
{% if content.field_example['#object'] is defined  %}
```

But what is the best method?

Comment: Use hook_preprocess and check programmatically, maybe add indicator variable. Otherwise what 4k4 wrote.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Like I also wrote in [How can you render fields from an entity reference in node templates? [Drupal 8]](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198694/how-can-you-render-fields-from-an-entity-reference-in-node-templates-drupal-8), content is a render array that contains data prepared for displaying.

If you want to check or compare something, use the values instead, which are available on the node object.

`{% if node.field_example.value %}`.

Note that the property depends on the field type. If it's a reference field, you need to use target_id instead. The referenced question links to a entity field API cheat sheet that lists common field types and their properties.

Comment: For image field {% node.field_article_image.target_id %}

Answer (score 20):

You can't be sure about the structure of the render array inside of content, so this is possible not the best method.

This may be a better solution:

```
{% if content.field_example|render|striptags|trim %}
  <p>field is not empty</p>
{% endif %}
```

This checks if rendering the field generates any output.

But this depends, how you have configured the field format and what you try to do. For example, you could have configured to display a label if the field is empty. Then you have to adjust this. If you don't depend on the rendered output and only want to check, if the field has a value in the database, use the node object. See Berdir's answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
{% if not (node.field_whatever.isEmpty ?? true) and content.field_whatever is defined %}
  <div class="whatever_markup">
    {{ content.field_whatever }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

This solution is quite bullet-proof and even working in reusealbe and/or shared templates (e.g. a shared `node--teaser.html.twig` accross multiple bundles) because

- it works for all field types
- it checks if the field exists
- it checks if the field is not empty
- it checks if the field is not hidden in display mode

This should work for any entity template, e.g. you can simply replace `node.field_whatever` with `paragraph.field_whatever` in a `paragraph.html.twig` template file.

Comment: Sorry, after your edit, did you miss a check? Shouldn't be `if not (node.field_whatever.isEmpty ?? true) and content.field_whatever is defined`? Otherwise as you wrote, doesn't work, at least for me with a filled field on D10.

Comment: Oh, of course, you're right, fixed it now

Answer (score 6):

Check if field is not empty in Twig templating (**Field Collection**)
*Template*: field-collection-item--field-services.html.twig

Install [Field Twig Value Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) to get the value using "**|field_value**", followed by "**is not empty**"

```
{% if content.field_work|field_value is not empty %}

       ...

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Option for content fields:

```
{% if content.field_name['#items'].getValue() %}
```