# If conditions in twig to check if field has a value

Tags: theming

I have used this below code to check if the field has a value

```
{% if content.field_title is not empty %}
    <p>{{ content.field_title }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

But p tag is rendering even though the field doesn't have a value. Same happening for `{% if content.field_title is not null %}` as well and `{{ dump(content.field_title) }}` is not an empty array if the field has no value. So how to check empty condition in twig for a field.

Edited: Trying to use the content object instead node/paragraph/term object. Here [Verify a field is not empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198570/verify-a-field-is-not-empty) used node object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few ways to check. For content fields in Twig I generally prefer:

```
{% if content.field_title['#items'].getValue() %}
```